# 404 не отдается апачем в случае если страница не существует?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Так не работает

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d       
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: во первых `ErrorDocement` не отдает саму страницу, а только устанавливает путь к ней. Во вторых, у вас все существующие и не существующие ссылку заворачиваются в `index.php`. Так что фактически ссылке всегда находится соответствующий ресурс

Comment: КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ ?

Comment: что значит использовать  единую точку входа или ErrorDocument 404?